# Validate laravel error

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to use `$this->validate` helper in Lumen. However, on the request, I need to do `$request->json()->all()` instead of `$request->all()` only because I can't get the exact parameters and its value (even if the fields has value it will still mark it as failed) when I use the latter.

**$request->json()->all()** output:

```
array:6 [
  "username" => ""
  "first_name" => "asaas"
  "last_name" => ""
  "email_address" => ""
  "password" => ""
  "password_confirmation" => ""
]
```

**$request->all()** output:

```
array:1 [
  "{"username":"","first_name":"asaas","last_name":"","email_address":"","password":"","password_confirmation":""}" => ""
]
```

Now, when I do pass `$request->json()->all()` on the helper:

```
$this->validate($request->json()->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|min:2|max:20',
    'first_name' => 'required|max:50',
    'last_name' => 'required|max:50',
    'email_address' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required',
]);
```

It will throw an error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller::validate() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in

as I expected, because the `$request` should be passed not the one with the `json()->all()`. What can I do to address the error?

Comment: Why do you have to use `$request->json()->all()`? You can't pass an array to the validate, it needs to be the Request object.

Answer (score 2):

Use the validator like so.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->json()->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|min:2|max:20',
    'first_name' => 'required|max:50',
    'last_name' => 'required|max:50',
    'email_address' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required',
]);
```

Then handle the validation check

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
}
```

Or

```
$this->validateWith($validator);
```